# Using a web service in Windows phone 7?

Tags: windows, web-services, windows-phone-7, service-reference

Is it possible to use a web service created as "ASP.NET web service application" in my windows phone 7 app?

I tired referencing it as follows after adding a service reference:
        Dim MyService As ServiceReference1.TrialService = New ServiceReference1.TrialService

However I got this error: "Type 'ServiceReference1.TrialService' is not defined."

This is the way i reference from my smart device application and it works, any idea how to do it in a windows phone 7 app?

Comment: Did you import the Namespace to the code behind ?

Comment: can you please elaborate on how to do that?

Comment: Just add using ServiceReference1; on the top before the namespace decalration.

Comment: Or in case of VB .. use IMPORTS.. Check my answer.

Comment: I dont think thats the problem though.. did not solve my problem. I have a feeling projects created as asp.net web services on visual studio 2008 are not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others to benefit: what i replaced that definition with is this:

```
    Dim MyService As ServiceReference1.TrialServiceSoapClient = New ServiceReference1.TrialServiceSoapClient()
```

That worked and I was able to call the methods in the web service successfully

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. You have to add service reference by right clicking service reference and then click on discover button and then select your service.then reference is added to your project. then you can use it.

Comment: I did that, as I mentioned in my question and I got the mentioned error. Now im using visual studio 2010 for the phone application and the web service was built using visual studio 2008 do you think that might be the issue? I tried searching for an option to create a web service in the visual studio 2010 but i didnt find it

Comment: I dont think it will matter if it is created in vs2008 or 2010. try to update reference by right clicking reference and then click on update service reference

Comment: hover your mouse on reference and then import namespace as well.

Answer (score 0):

After the service reference has been added to the solution make sure you import the namespace onto the page.

**C#**

```
using ServiceReference1;
```

**VB**

```
Imports ServiceReference1
```

Please let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help however that did not solve my problem what did solve my problem is replacing that definition with this:  Dim MyService As ServiceReference1.TrialServiceSoapClient = New ServiceReference1.TrialServiceSoapClient()

Comment: Im actually not quite convinced why it just worked this way. Do you have any explanation for that?

Comment: When you add service reference it creates a set of classes that it names as Client. With has all the metadata of the entire service. We are not calling WCF directly.. rather we are calling this funcntion creatd at the time of service reference addition. Clear ?